# How to minimize execution time while executing a test class with bulk(200) insert and update

Tags: unit-test, community, service-cloud-console, servicecloud

Test class execution taking too much time -

How to minimize execution time while executing a test class with bulk(200) insert and update in salesforce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test class execution time depends on below points:

- Logic by which you are preparing your data for test class.
- Triggers execution time when you create test data.
- Class logic for which you are doing testing.

You can reduce this time by following consideration

- If you are just creating data for a class in which you are not testing trigger, you can bypass trigger execution using static flags.

I can help you if you provide some more details.